# Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml

This has come up a few times, and I've been struggling with it all day in a UWP app.

My specific issue was that I was using x:Bind inside a ContentTemplate that was inside a DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="IFactionMember">
  <Button Command="{x:Bind **Property of IFactionMember**}"> // Good
    <Button.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Padding="10,0">
          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind **Property of IFactionMember**}" /> // Bad
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
  </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

You cannot do this :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use `{Binding}` instead for your scenario, for example:

```
<ListView x:Name="listview" ItemsSource="{x:Bind members}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:IFactionMember">
            <Button > 
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
                        <Grid Padding="10,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding  testtext}" />  
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[x:bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) lacks some of the features of `{Binding}`, in `x:Bind`, `Path` is rooted at the Page by default, not the `DataContext`, it seems like if you are using `x:bind` here, it will try to find the property at the `MainPage`, so that it will not find the correct property.